# Отправка SMS-сообщения на Android

Tags: android

Как отправить смс-сообщение по нажатию на кнопку?
Знаю про Smsmanager, но дальше не запрыгнул.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, null, null);
```

И нужно разрешение (в манифесте):

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
> ```

Comment: И нужно разрешение:
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>`

Comment: Подобные дополнения лучше размещать сразу в ответе, используя ссылку "править".

Comment: Дополнение добавил)